# How do I specify a channel for the FX function in Magick++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Here is the article describing usage FX-feature in ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx

I need to use FX with the Magick++ (C++). How do I specify the channel with which I am working? For example: imagemagick command line:

```
convert  -size 64x64 xc:black -channel blue -fx '1/2' fx_navy.gif
```

how to translate it to Magick++? I can do something like this:

```
Magick::Image img( Magick::Geometry( 64, 64 ), Magick::Color( "black" ) );
img.fx( "1/2" );
img.write( "fx_navy.gif" );
```

<-- but it's for ALL CHANNELS not only for the blue channel. Actually it will be gray color or something like that. How to specify a channel?

Or how to do something like this in terms of Magick++?

```
convert -size 100x100 xc: +size xc:red xc:yellow xc:lime \
          -fx 'ar=1/max(1,  (i-50)*(i-50)+(j-10)*(j-10)  );
               br=1/max(1,  (i-10)*(i-10)+(j-70)*(j-70)  );
               cr=1/max(1,  (i-90)*(i-90)+(j-90)*(j-90)  );
               ( u[1]*ar + u[2]*br + u[3]*cr )/( ar+br+cr )' \
          gradient_shepards.gif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `Magick::Image.fx` is the channel selector.

```c++
Magick::Image img( Magick::Geometry( 64, 64 ), Magick::Color( "black" ) );
img.fx( "1/2", Magick::BlueChannel );
```

For the second question. You'll need to leverage some of the STL methods & techniques.

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Magick++.h>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<Magick::Image> imgList;
    Magick::Image canvas(Magick::Geometry( 100, 100 ), Magick::Color( "NONE" ));
    imgList.push_back(canvas);
    {
        Magick::Image red(Magick::Geometry( 100, 100 ), Magick::Color( "RED" ));
        Magick::Image yellow(Magick::Geometry( 100, 100 ), Magick::Color( "YELLOW" ));
        Magick::Image lime(Magick::Geometry( 100, 100 ), Magick::Color( "LIME" ));

        imgList.push_back(red);
        imgList.push_back(yellow);
        imgList.push_back(lime);
    }
    std::string expression("ar=1/max(1,  (i-50)*(i-50)+(j-10)*(j-10)  );"
                           "br=1/max(1,  (i-10)*(i-10)+(j-70)*(j-70)  );"
                           "cr=1/max(1,  (i-90)*(i-90)+(j-90)*(j-90)  );"
                           "( u[1]*ar + u[2]*br + u[3]*cr )/( ar+br+cr )");
    Magick::fxImages(&canvas, imgList.begin(), imgList.end(), expression);
    canvas.write("/tmp/output.png");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed answer! I would give you 100 votes at time if I could! :) It's more detailed than official tutorial! :)